Vlookup using office script in PA Cloud returns NA values
I have created office script which vlookups 7/8 columns from another file in SharePoint. Whenever I run the script from Excel Desktop, the vlookups fetch data accurately.
But, if the same script is run through power automate the results of vlookups are all #N/A.
Do we know why the results are always NA when it gets run through PA Cloud? Bothe the files are on the same SharePoint Folder.
If it gets failed/ having limitations, then second option I see, is copy the data from the source sheets of files and paste in the excel where I need to do vlookups.
But then, how to do the second option? The data is huge, and not on table so I would need to copy full sheet only.
One of the vlookup formula am using in Office Script is:
selectedSheet.getRange("K" + tnn + ":K" + Ir_used).setFormulaR1C1("=IF(ISNA (VLOOKUP(RC[-8],'" + workbookURL + "/[T_MV_Report.xlsx]Report'!CS:C10,6, 0)),0,VLOOKUP(RC[-8],'" + workbookURL + "/[T_MV_Report.xlsx] Report'!CS:C10,6,0))");


To run the office script on power automate, your data needs to be on one file. You can either move the data to one file and run the script using 'run script from SharePoint' by storing the script externally. (built in / office embedded scripts often don't work properly)
or
other option is to fetch the source excel data to power automate, do the necessary lookups via filter array and similar actions and inject it back to the destination excel.
edit: to generate tables in runtime, you can use this script:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let firstWorkSheet = workbook.getFirstWorksheet();
    let fullUsedRange = firstWorkSheet.getUsedRange();
    workbook.addTable(fullUsedRange, true);
}


So, everything in one excel. How can I achieve that using power automate? Like I have dynamic 150k+ rows in 4/5 sheets across two workbook. How can I make all the sheet in one workbook?

retrieve the tables one by one and them put them in a separate sheet . you may be interested in exploring graph api but that's when you've got some time to experiment with it. but other than that for quick resolution, just get all rows from each table one by one, create table in a new sheet and push the rows.
you start with getting the worksheets from both files and creating new sheets in a single file (the merged one). then you start getting rows from each of the older worksheets and push them to newer ones.

What if the sheets are not having any table, all are just data no formatting no table. Do I need to create table then first?

you have two options. either create the tables manually or run a script. I will add the script to answer above so you can create tables using script (if you have multiple sources expected dynamically). running scripts is not needed if this is a one time activity.

Doesn't get data more than 4k rows
